# in monopoly do you collect 200 if you get sent to the nearest trainstation or fleet street but the card doesn't state collect or do not collect on it

Tags: monopoly

When you land on a chance or community chest card and it states you have to travel to a certain street/railway or Utility but do you collect 200 for passing GO as the card doesn't state if you should or shouldn't like some other cards do.

[image]

Found the actual card:

[image]

Comment: Which card(s) in particular? You mention it doesn't state if you should or shouldn't collect $200 _like some other cards do_, so which cards don't mention it? As far as I remember, the only card which states that you don't collect $200 if passing go is the "Go to Jail". All of the other cards (to the best of my memory) mention to collect $200 if passing GO

Comment: i believe the card is one that states you should travel to the nearest railway station, if the station is unowned you can buy it, if owned then  you have to pay twice the amount you owe the owner.

Comment: @bLAZYY - Please do some research and edit it into the question. Currently this sounds like "I remember such and such and it doesn't make sense". If you can provide actual quotes from / pictures of the cards which demonstrates your point, then this would become a valid question.

Comment: @AndyT the game is currently with my brother for Christmas so wont be able to get a picture of the specific card until the 25th so i edited the Question with an example of what the card looks like but utility is used instead of railway the concept is still the same.

Comment: @bLAZYY - Doesn't need to be your actual set, your example picture is acceptable proof that such a card exists. This card doesn't exist in any set I've ever played with, hence my previous expectation that you were misremembering.

Answer (score 3):

The *next* location always means in travel direction, and your figure will move along the board as if you rolled a number equal to the distance. If you pass GO on the way, you will indeed collect 200 dollars, as stated in the [official rules](http://richard_wilding.tripod.com/monorules.htm#go):

> Each time a player's token lands on or passes over GO, whether by throwing the dice or drawing a card, the Banker pays that player a $200 salary.

This is true for all cards, except for the card that states "Go directly to Jail", meaning you don't traverse the board as normal. You can think of your figure being teleported there - so you don't get 200 dollars either.

> When you are sent to Jail you cannot collect your $200 salary in that move since, regardless of where your token is on the board, you must move directly into Jail. (...)

Comment: Often the card says, say, "*Advance* to Mayfair", so clearly if you start between Mayfair and Go, you collect 200: if not, not.

Comment: @TimLymington Its impossible to Pass Go when traveling to Mayfair from anywhere on the board as Mayfair is the last position on the board.

Comment: My confusion is why some cards state "if you pass go collect 200" and others simply don't, its not like they have no room to write it.

Answer (score 1):

Game play in Monopoly is in a clockwise direction.  "Advance" means to move one's token in Monopoly's normal direction of movement (clockwise).

If, while following "Chance" or "Community Chest" instructions to "advance" to the target location, one passes "GO" one would collect $200.

Note: "Advance to the nearest ______".  Would not have one go counter-clockwise (fall back, retreat, reverse) even if by doing so one would arrive at the nearest _______.   "Advance" is the operative word; not "nearest".